# iOS 5 - connect to an HTTPS server

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I am trying to overcome the change done in iOS 5 regarding the NSURLConnection.

Basically the methods changed, so if you need to connect to a site that uses HTTPS and send credentials to authenticate, you cannot do it anymore, because many methods were deprecated.

Is there any place where I can get a working example of how should I write the code to use iOS5 compliant code? I've check the documentation and the headers but not a single source around show me how to make such connection with an example, that shows where the code goes in which file (assume that I just start from a standard template from Xcode, like the single view  template or the tab bar template).

I would really appreciate any suggestion; Since my app will run on iOS 5 I would like to use the new procedure, but the lack of documentation and tutorials are making my task harder than what I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the NSURLCredentialStorage singleton. You need to add the credentials to the storage before using NSURLConnection by calling one of the NSURLCredentialStorage methods, for instance:

```
- (void)setCredential:(NSURLCredential *)credential forProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
```

Comment: Thanks Joris, so these are the steps that I should follow?

1:add the delegate to NSURLConnectionDelegate to my ViewController 2: Add the credentials to the NSURLCredentialStorage 3: pass the credentials as in your snippet?

Comment: No, the method I showed is to add them to the CredentialStorage. Once they are there just use your NSURLConnection without worrying about credentials. If they are in the NSCredentialStorage they will be used automatically.

Comment: thanks for the clarification Joris; never used the NSURLCredential before :)

Comment: Hi, could you show the steps on how you implement that method? I am a little lost here. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:
       (NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

if ([challenge previousFailureCount] <= maxRetryCount ) {
    NSURLCredential *newCredential =
    [NSURLCredential
     credentialWithUser: userName
     password:password
     persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    [[challenge sender]
     useCredential:newCredential
     forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

   }
   else
   {
     NSLog(@"Failure count %d",[challenge previousFailureCount]);
   }
}
```

This works fine for me. However,  it looks like self signed certificates are accepted too. I probably need to post a separate question about that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jan; indeed it works but it would accept any certificate that is self signed; I will have to use the solution that Joris mentioned.

Comment: Hi user1006198, I found a solution that works with this method. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564812/preventing-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-ios5 ; I need to have a challenge method (rather than the singleton approach of Joris, because I need to re-display a login box if the session invalidates and I don't want to store user credentials longer than the duration of a session.